# How to configure Source code analysis for Monorepo?

Tags: sonarqube, monorepo, sonarcloud

I have a Mono repo in which all my Spring boot based micro service reside.

I know how to configure a SonarQube analysis for poly repo but wondering how sonarqube analysis can be done on a monorepo and how Soanarqube can identify different projects inside the mono repo.

Is there a different type of configuration I have to do with Sonarqube ?

Comment: What is a "Mono repo" ?

Comment: See here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo

Comment: @Spencer Bharath Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: On 1 on july they finally added support for GitHub (and earlier for Azure DevOps).
I haven't it yet, will be setting it up now.
but in case anybody else is interested the documentation is here https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/setup-monorepo/

Comment: the OP is for SonarQube as well.  I am wondering how it is for the on-prem version

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, monorepo support is available for [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [Azure DevOps Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/). If your repository is hosted by one of these services, you can import a monorepo with this procedure:

> - Go to the + (plus) menu on the top right of the SonarCloud interface and select Analyze new project.
> - This will take you to the Analyze projects page
> - Now click Setup a monorepo (it is a small text link on the lower right of the page). You will now be on the Import monorepo page.
> - Select the organization and then select the monorepo repository that you want to import.
> - For each project contained in your monorepo, add a corresponding SonarCloud project by clicking "Add new project". You have to choose a unique project key for each SonarCloud project. As mentioned above, these are the keys that you will use when configuring your CI service (see below) to bind each monorepo project to its corresponding SonarCloud project.

Full details in the sonar blog post: [Mono-repository support for GitHub and Azure DevOps Services available now!](https://blog.sonarsource.com/mono-repository-support-for-github-and-azure-devops)

Note that:

- there is also a support for [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) : [Mono-repository support for Bitbucket Cloud now available for SonarCloud!](https://blog.sonarsource.com/mono-repository-support-for-bitbucket-cloud-available-for-sonarcloud)
- You can show your interest in a monorepo support for [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) to Sonarsource by voting [here](https://portal.productboard.com/sonarsource/1-sonarcloud/c/17-monorepo-support-for-gitlab).

Comment: If I understand the documentation and behavior of the Sonarcloud UI correctly, doing this requires setting up a PAT in Azure Devops which is tied to an AD user. For various reasons, tying our CI pipeline to a specific user is not best practice.

Is there any alternative method for setting up the monorepo in Sonarcloud that does not require a PAT?

Comment: @Fred, I believe setting up Sonarcloud generally requires a PAT. Rather than tying the PAT to a real person who may eventually move on from the company, I've created a "service account" its only purpose is to be the account referenced when we don't want to tie things to a real user. It is by no means a perfect solution, as the next question is, "how do people access this account when a new PAT needs to be generated for something else?" but it's the best solution I've seen so far for handling long-lived things that we don't want to break when someone leaves the company.

Answer (score 1):

As of writing [SonarQube 9.8](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest) does not mention the word `monorepos` in their documentation search.  So you'd have to create separate projects manually if you are using an on-prem version.